# Find Elements in a Contaminated Binary Tree

Tags: c++, set

```
FindElements(TreeNode *root)
{
    if (!root)
        return;
    if (root->val == -1)
    {
        root->val = 0;
        m.insert((root->val));
        cout << (root->val) << m.count((root->val)) << " ";
    }
    if (root->left != NULL)
    {
        root->left->val = (root->val * 2) + 1;

        m.insert((root->val * 2) + 1);
        cout << (root->val * 2) + 1 << m.count((root->val * 2) + 1) << " ";
    }
    if (root->right != NULL)
    {
        root->right->val = (root->val * 2) + 2;

        m.insert((root->val * 2) + 2);

        cout << (root->val * 2) + 2 << m.count((root->val * 2) + 2) << " ";
    }
    FindElements(root->left);
    FindElements(root->right);
}
unordered_set<int> m;
```

when in above function I'm inserting value in set it's showing the count =1

but when checking in the below function it is showing their cost =0
and it's showing cost=0 for last elements,
only

```
bool find(int target)
{
    // cout<<target<<m.count(target)<<" ";
    return m.count(target);
}
```

```
input:
["FindElements","find","find","find"]
[[[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]],[1],[3],[4]]

sout:
01 11 21 31 41 11 30 40
```

the above values till 41 are from FindElements(TreeNode *root),,, and rest are from bool find(int target)

```
output:
[null,true,false,false]
expected:
[null,true,true,true]
```

Comment: I did a string search on your "question" and there is no `?` character. What exactly is your question?

Comment: in FindElements(TreeNode *root) function I'm inserting some values in the set (m) which i'm constantly printing to make sure it is well inserted in the set(m)....but when i'm checking the presence of the particular value(same which i have inserted in the FindElements(TreeNode *root)  ) in the set in bool find(int target) function ,its not showing

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why does "findElements" do insertions? what is `m`? A bit more context would be helpful.

Comment: unordered_set<int> m;

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/find-elements-in-a-contaminated-binary-tree/

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see if the unordered_set is created correctly?

Comment: i dont have a premium account

Comment: ah, right you're coding on "leet code". in the `find` function, print everything in the `unordered_set`. See if the values are still there.